# CanExecute part of a command is not called in all cases. what does determine it?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, canexecute

In my WPF application using MVVM I noticed that in some cases the CanExecute part of a Command is not called, so I was wondering what decides when this (kind of) method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CanExecute` is called by a control when it is told by raising the [`CanExecuteChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx), how exactly controls handle `Commands` is up to them (they could for example also call it again when the `CommandParameter` changes), but if you want them to reevaluate `CanExecute` you should fire the event manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I have a feel my MVVM application is getting more complicated than before I used MVVM but I cannot really formulate a simple question how to fix that.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: MVVM does have some overhead but it pays off. Also some MVVM frameworks handle certain areas better than others.

Comment: Yes I know ... until now I think it has more advantages than disadvantages, even though my application is not completely suitable for MVVM (because it has a lot of memory mapped data instead of separate variables to act on).